# Location of the "More Apps" icon

Tags: unity, 11.10, icons

Can someone help me find the location of the "More Apps" icon?  It's the icon that you click on in the Dash Home button to bring up the search applications screen.  When you click on the Dash Home button you'll the button/icon "More Apps".

I have created a routine to allow me to click on an icon on the Launcher to bring up the "Search Applications" screen, but at present it just has a question mark "?" for the icon.

Thanks in advance for any help in facilitating me with access to this specific Icon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the icon for the "More Apps" launcher (as currently no ability exists to have this feature in a lens).

The Functionality is for:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11383700&postcount=23

Hope anyone having the question of location of the Icons they see with Unity can benefit from this information.

There are a few locations of the icons (to name a few):

```
/usr/share/app-install/icons
/usr/share/unity-2d/places/artwork
/usr/share/unity/themes
/usr/share/unity/4
```

Thanks to anyone who looked at my question and performed any research to help.  Hope this helps someone else.